# Problem with subscriber

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
I'm using a roboteq magsensor, and I want to read data from.  so I'm going to use Roboteq Linux API to interface one the sensor form a C++   ROS node through CANbus . The problem is I didn't come to know how to work: it's only one node that's gonna read from the sensor , how to use topic in this situation ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300632/problem-with-subscriber/) by [ameni](https://answers.ros.org/users/36994/ameni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A node that reads sensor data is usually just a publisher, not a subscriber.

This node will use the Roboteq Linux API to read the sensor data, then it will publish that sensor data to the ROS network in a topic.

Then if you want to use that sensor data for something, you would write a separate node that subscribes to that topic.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2018-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ameni](https://answers.ros.org/users/36994/ameni/) on 2018-08-15**:
Okey, a publisher node will read sensor data using Roboteq Linux API,

My problem is: I didn't come to know how to implement the API, especially when i don't know how the node will read data , because i don't know how to use the "topic" in this situation

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2018-08-15**:
Have you went through the [beginner tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) already? If not, I would suggest going through them before going any farther.